# iptables - drop packets on input, but allow outgoing

Tags: debian, iptables

I'm running `Debian` and `iptables`.
I'm creating a `proxy` server, and would like `DROP` packets entering with a certain source IP address, but sniff them with `pcap`.
Then afterwards allow to manually send packets out of the server with same source IP address - while `NAT`ing them with a public IP.

I've tried this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 79.43.211.10 --persistent
```

It seems the `DROP` isn't respected, and `packets` are sent all the way through the server.

I wish to allow packets entering the server, then dropped. But I should be able to manually send out packets also from "within" the server.

**UPDATE**

Removing `FORWARD` seems to be OK.

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j DROP
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 79.43.211.10 --persistent
```

It seems `packets` are not going out the server, but it isn't because of my `DROP` rule, `iptables -nvL` shows:

```
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       192.168.0.0/24        0.0.0.0/0
```

And using `scapy` to create a `ICMP` doesn't get `NAT`ed with public IP address?

Comment: Traffic that's passed through the `FORWARD` chain doesn't also pass through the `INPUT` or `OUTPUT` chains on its way through the server.  So although you don't give any concrete examples, it seems likely to me that what you're being surprised by is a misunderstanding about netfilter.

Comment: Ah, I see. i'll test without.

Comment: Update with new example.

Comment: Ah, seems `scapy` bypasses `iptables` also on `NAT`? Hm, what to do...

Comment: It shouldn't.  But you're not posting your usage cases, nor the details and results of tests, so it's hard to comment.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here, anyway?

Comment: The thing troubling me now is that `Scapy` does indeed create the `ICMP` `packet`, but it doesn't reach `SNAT` in `iptables`. Reading the docs about `Scapy` does show that it uses `raw` `socket` which doesn't reach `netfilter`.